# What are the definitions of each of the Lifecycle Events in Orchard's CMS?

Tags: orchardcms

The documentation for content handlers in Orchard mentions `Lifecycle Events` (http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-content-handlers).

Most events are self explanatory, but I was wondering if anybody can tell me the differences between `OnActivated`, `OnInitializing`, and `OnLoading`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In firing order:

- **`OnActivated`** - content item object hierarchy has been created, but not yet fetched from db

  Used for preparing content part for further usage. Eg. setting getters and setters for lazy loaded objects, setting up delegates etc. Think of it as of a "constructor" for a given part.
- **`OnInitializing`** - content item object hierarchy has been created, but not yet fetched from db.

  Used for setting initial/default property values for a given part.
- **`OnLoading`** - content item is about to be loaded from db.

  Used for various things. Fired only if an item exists in the database and is about to be loaded. Orchard core uses this event to set up lazy loaders for part records.
- **`OnLoaded`** - content item has been loaded from db

  Used for various things. Fired only if an item exists in the database and all record loaders have been set. You can be sure that `part.Record` will not be null for any part at this point and will contain data fetched from database.

Comment: Great thanks. I actually asked this question so I knew the correct event to set my setters and getters- now I know I should be using OnActivated. If I get a chance, I'll update the Orchard documentation with these definitions, but it may be useful if someone who can define the rest of the events in as much detail also updated the remaining events.

Comment: Cool! In general - yes. Actually the usage of each event is not written in stone. The description above can be considered a best practice as it's how Orchard core handles things, but you may encounter different approaches depending on scenario - eg. if you'd want to vary your setters/getters based on record data for some reason - you should use *OnLoaded*.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks.