# How to introduce additional auto increment or Guid field to a custom Orchard content part?

Tags: asp.net, .net, orchardcms, guid, database-schema

I'm trying to extend the UserType with a custom AccountPart. 
I don't want user account id to be a content part id, i want AccountId field to be an independent auto increment 5 digit number (like 10300, 10301) or at least auto generated Guid.

I've tried number of times to achieve it, but still didn't.
Here is on of my tries. The result is 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 for the 1st user, and for the second i got an exception. The Guid didn't generated =(.

AccountPart:

```
      public Guid AccountId
    {
        get { return Record.AccountId; }
        set { Record.AccountId = Guid.NewGuid(); }
    }
    public decimal RealMoney
    {
        get { return Record.RealMoney; }
        set { Record.RealMoney = value; }
    }
    public decimal VirtualMoney
    {
        get { return Record.VirtualMoney; }
        set { Record.VirtualMoney = value; }
    }
    public decimal BonusPoints
    {
        get { return Record.BonusPoints; }
        set { Record.BonusPoints = value; }
    }
```

Migratord:

```
   SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("AccountPartRecord",
                                  table => table
                                              .ContentPartRecord()
                                              .Column<Guid>("AccountId", 
                                                                x => x
                                                                    .WithType(DbType.Guid)
                                                                    .Unique()
                                                                    .NotNull()))

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("AccountPart",
                                                     builder => builder.Attachable());

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("User",
                                                     cfg => cfg.WithPart("AccountPart"));
```

Also i've tried to add AccountId this way:

```
        SchemaBuilder.ExecuteSql(@"
  ALTER TABLE [BetIt].[dbo].[Betit_AccountPartRecord]
    ADD AccountId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID()");
```

It behaves the same - sets emty Guid to each new user. But if i open Sql Management Studio an add new record manually it'll generate a random Guid.
I'm completely confused...

**Update:**
I've actually acheived auto Guid generation for the Content Part by using handlers. But it looks more like workaround to me. I don't belive this is the only way to generate unique value.

Migrators:

```
     SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("AccountPartRecord",
                                  table => table
                                            .ContentPartRecord()
                                            .Column<long>("AccountId", 
                                                       x => x
                                                           .WithType(DbType.Guid)
                                                           .NotNull()
                                                           .Unique())
```

Part:

```
      public class AccountPart : ContentPart<AccountPartRecord>
{
    public Guid AccountId
    {
        get { return Record.AccountId; }
        set { Record.AccountId = value; }
    }
     }
```

Handler:

```
    public class AccountPartHandler : ContentHandler
{
    public AccountPartHandler(IRepository<AccountPartRecord> repository)
    {
        Filters.Add(new ActivatingFilter<AccountPart>("User"));
        Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));

        OnCreating<AccountPart>((context, accountPart) =>
            accountPart.AccountId = Guid.NewGuid());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up values through handler is not a workaround and it's actually the preferred way (take a look eg. at how `IdentityPart` unique identifier is set). All logic should be kept in code, not database (which is just a data store). This means that `Guid` and/or custom identifier generation should be there as well.

Please note that Orchard always creates an empty record first and then fills it with values. In this case columns with `NotNull` and/or `Unique` constraints can cause problems. Try to avoid them.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! Then i have other questions:
Why is an Identity field is type of string in code and in Db?

Should i move Guid generation from OnCreating event to the OnInitializating event?

Can i create auto increment field and how =)

Comment: 1. Because logically identity can be anything - it's Guid by default, but you can provide your own identifiers. 2. Yes, you should - `OnInitializing` is a place for setting up default values (I wrote a detailed description of various events here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441705/what-are-the-definitions-of-each-of-the-lifecycle-events-in-orchards-cms). 3. Good question - need to investigate this a bit more (never had to use it, honestly)