# How to access Part properties during the Creating event in Orchard CMS

Tags: c#, events, handler, orchardcms

I need to hook into the Creating event in Orchard CMS and use the Title of the content that's being created (Along with some other properties) to create an item in a 3rd party system and return the ID of that to set in the content type in Orchard.

I have a custom content type, but when I try to hook into the events (as explained in the docs [here](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-content-handlers) and also by looking at code on the built in Orchard Core content parts) all properties are null.

Are they just lazy loaded? Is there a way to populate them? Overriding any of the shape methods (GetItemMetadata / BuildDisplayShape / BuildEditorShape / UpdateEditorShape) doesn't seem right as this should only fire when initially creating the content type.

My code is:

```
public MyContentPartHandler(IRepository<MyContentPartRecord> repository, IOrchardServices orchardServices, Lazy<IMyContentPartService> myContentPartService) {
    _orchardServices = orchardServices;
    _myContentPartService = myContentPartService;
    Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));

    OnCreating<MyContentPart>(CreateTPItemAndAssignIdentity);
}
protected void CreateTPItemAndAssignIdentity(CreateContentContext context, MyContentPart part)
{
    //create item in 3rd party system
    var item = _myContentPartService.Value.CreateNewItem(part.Title, part.Path);
    part.ExternalIdentity = item.FriendlyId;
}
```

The `CreateNewItem()` method fails as the `part.Title` and `part.Path` are null. Do I need to try and get at the Record? (I thought not, as the Orchard CMS record has not been created at that point)

UPDATE - I have also tried to use the `OnCreated` event instead, but I run into the same problem with the properties not being populated. I place a breakpoint in the code, and noticed that when the `OnCreated` breakpoint was hit - the data did not actually exist in the database at that time.

Comment: I think that it is better to use OnCreated, beacuse at that point you should have all the other parts loaded.

Comment: just tried it in OnCreated and no change - none of the properties are populated. :/
I will update the original question too to show the attempt - thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnCreating/OnCreated` events are fired when an item object is constructed, not populated with data.

If you want to be sure that data is already there, use either `OnPublished` event (fired after item has been updated) or `OnLoading/OnLoaded` events if you want to run some code after an item has been fully loaded from database.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441705/what-are-the-definitions-of-each-of-the-lifecycle-events-in-orchards-cms) description of certain events might also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, so just to be clear - OnPublished is not necessarily when a user has clicked the "Publish Now" button? It could just be a save of an item?

Comment: Yes, but not for every item. If item is draftable (has both "Save" and "Publish Now" buttons), `OnPublished` will be fired only on hitting the latter. Non-draftable items (like widgets eg.) are published implicitly whevever they are saved (ie. their "Save" button acts like "Publish Now"). So the event gets fired after hitting "Save" then.