# Orchard ContentPart OnCreating Event

Tags: orchardcms

I'm writing a custom ContentHandler for a custom ContentPart. I was trying to use the OnCreating lifecycle event to set a value on my ContentPart before the new record was inserted into the database, but it appears that the record is created prior to my event handler being called.

```
public class MyPartHandler: ContentHandler
{
    public MyPartHandler(
        IClock clock,
        IRepository<MyPartRecord> repository)
    {
        this.Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));

        OnCreating<CustomerPart>((CreateContentContext context, MyPartRecord myPart) =>
        {
            myPart.CreatedUtc = clock.UtcNow;
        });
    }
}
```

Worth noting that the result is the same except that an extra database UPDATE is involved.

A few questions:

1. Is my observation accurate that the OnCreating event happens after the part record is inserted into the database?
2. If so when exactly does this event occur?
3. Are the lifecycle events documented anywhere in any detail? I see a list of them here http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-content-handlers#LifecycleEvents but without any real desription of when they occur.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `OnActivated` event. It is the first event called in the content item lifecycle.

Comment: So when does this event actually happen in relation to creating a new content item / part? Looking for more details of how the life cycle actually flows.

Comment: This question contains a pretty good explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441705/what-are-the-definitions-of-each-of-the-lifecycle-events-in-orchards-cms